# Cannot call function template with function argument

Tags: c++, templates

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on with the following complex mix of argument types in this function template that I need to call that I am missing. I am trying to call a function template that has this signature:

```
template <class T> list<T> map(T (*f)(const T &i), const list<T> &il);
```

My code looks like this:

```
int successor(int n) {
    return n+1;
}

int main ()
{
    list<int> seq = ez_list(0,1,2,3,4);  // I know that this part is right
    map(successor, seq); // this function call is not recognized
    return 0;
}
```

Eclipse says " Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: list<#0> map(#0 (*)(const #0 &), const list<#0>" but I don't see how that's different from what I have. Please explain to me what is wrong with my arguments, i.e. how they fail to match the function template signature and what they should be like to fit it.

Edit: Thanks everyone for your suggestions on how to make this cleaner, unfortunately the definition of map is from someone else's code that I just have to work with. I will keep in mind your suggestions for my future use.

Comment: In the spirit of the STL, you could take iterators and any callable object. Then you wouldn't have these problems, someone could use a container other than `std::list`, and someone could pass in a type other than a raw function pointer. Of course an iterator pair can be replaced by a template parameter for the container.

Comment: Unrelated to your errors, I would suggest you take a hint from the standard library, which doesn't really use function pointers *or* fixed containers. So your `map` function could be something like `template<typename Iter, typename Func> Iter map(Iter begin, Iter end, Func func);` Which reminds very much [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) function, and is somewhat similar to [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int successor(int n)` is not the same as `int successor(const int& n)`

Which is what the template instantiation expects.

Answer (score 0):

What @StoryTeller said is correct... but there's more to it than that.

This will solve the immediate problems, which are that the function signature doesn't match because of the constant parameter and you have to pass the *address* of the function....

```
int successor(const int& n) {
    return n+1;
}

int main ()
{
    list<int> seq = ez_list(0,1,2,3,4);  
    map(&successor, seq); // pass the address of the function
    return 0;
}
```

Now, for the second problem.  For the love of everyone reading your code in the future, *please don't do it this way.*  Use a functor instead:

```
template<typename T>
class MyFunctor 
{
   public:
   T operator()(const T& arg) 
   {
      //Do your function work in here...
   }
}
```

(See http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html for an in-depth description of function objects)

Of course, that can be pretty terse, so if you'd like to wrap a function pointer instead, C++ has a facility for it.  Now you can wrap your function object without the confusing pointer syntax:

```
#include <functional>

template <class T> list<T> map(std::function<T(const T&), const list<T> &il);

int successor(int n) {
    return n+1;
}

int main ()
{
    list<int> seq = ez_list(0,1,2,3,4);  // I know that this part is right

    std::function<T (const T&)> successor = std::bind(&successor, std::placeholders::_1);

    map(successor, seq); // Look, ma, no function pointer!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Umm, there should be no difference between expressions `&successor` and `successor`. Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_functions
So, I don't see any substantial addition to the accepted answer in your answer, with the exception of the advice to use functors.